# Flutter android build.gradle unable to resolve class GradleException

Tags: android, flutter

In my flutter app, `flutter build apk` succeeds without warning but android.app.build.gradle has an error in this code:

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

The error is

> unable to resolve class GradleException

`whereis flutter` returns "/home/mark/dev/flutter/bin/flutter".

flutter doctor -v returns Flutter version 3.3.1 on channel stable at /home/mark/dev/flutter` and has no errors.

my `local.properties` file contains `flutter.sdk=/home/mark/dev/flutter`

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: It will work fine. Looks like you are new with flutter. You cannot remove this error

Comment: I just commented that line and hard coded my sdk path in and it works fine. I can confirm that it works fine even with the error so I assume this is just a linter error.

Comment: I do not recommend you to comment that line. Maybe it will work with debug mode. You should try to run relese mode or try to build apk.

Comment: The release apk builds fine.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove the `new` keyword before `GradleException`.

try this

```
throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

Comment: Don't do this, Groovy requires the `new` keyword when raising exceptions.

Comment: @DarkNeuron can you expand or share a bit more on this? Just curious to learn. Personal workaround was simply to replace with FileNotFoundException()

Comment: could you explain more why this error was thrown and since groovy needs new to throw expection what can be done and thiis a auto generated file not something which i created

Comment: The new keyword in Groovy is used to create a new instance of a class. In this case, the new keyword is used to create a new instance of the GradleException class.

If you remove the new keyword and just use GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file."), Groovy will interpret this as a reference to a static method on the GradleException class called GradleException(). Since no such method exists, you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 18):

**Do not remove the `new` keyword in the gradle file**

This is basically a false positive in VSCode. There is no problem with `GradleException`, or the `new` keyword. You can double check by opening the project in Android Studio and verify that `GradleException` indeed does exist.

If it annoys you that VSCode thinks this is an error, you can **probably** change `GradleException` to just `Exception`.

Answer (score 9):

Replace `GradleException` with `FileNotFoundException`

```
throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

This should fix the lint error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error too and tried all the solutions I found on the internet but it didn't work. Then I deleted the things in the extensions and realized the solution was to delete the Gradle for the Java package. In short, delete Gradle for Java from the extensions section. This was the solution for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).