# Error in flutter app : "unable to resolve class GradleException"

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-local-notification

I included the ["flutter_local_notifications"](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package in my app, and after that I got an error in android/app/build.gradle file.

This is the error :
"unable to resolve class GradleException"

I am getting the error in the line inside if block part of this part of code snippet :

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

I tried removing the package but the error didn't go away. When I tried to re-run the app, I got the following message:
"You don't have an extention for debugging Gradle. Should we find a Gradle extention in the marketplace?"

I tried the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700307/flutter-android-build-gradle-unable-to-resolve-class-gradleexception) on stackoverflow,
even after implemneting those answers, I am unable to run the app, I get the same error meesage "You don't have an extention for debugging Gradle. Should we find a Gradle extention in the marketplace?" and nothing happens if I click on the get extention button since I already have required extentions installed.
Also, I tried the top two solutions of the question in the link above, after implementing the first answer, the error went away, but I got the warning unknown keyword "do not" in settings.json file.
I tried the solutions again, changed the GradleException to Exception, this time, the error went away but I still can,t run my app, I am getting follwoing error message :
"You don't have an extention for debugging 'JSON with comments'. Should we find a 'JSON with comments' extention in marketplace?"

When I changed 'Exception' back to 'GradleException', the error comes back adn when I try to run the app, I get the follwoing message:
"You don't have an extention for debugging Gradle. Should we find a Gradle extention in the marketplace?"

Please help!